# How to call a Python function from a Tcl script

Tags: python, tcl

I have a Python script, say `pyscr.py`. Let's say this file defines the following function:

```
def f1() :
    print ('python func executing')
```

How do I call this function `f1` from a Tcl script?

Comment: I don't know the python syntax, but you'd do something like `set python_output [exec python -c {import "pyscr.py"; f1}]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a Tcl script to define a procedure to execute a Python script, and then call the procedure. Try this:

```
#! /usr/bin/tclsh
proc call_python {} {
    set output [exec python pyscr.py]
    puts $output
}

call_python
```

Comment: This only executes the python module. I am not interested in executing the module alone. I am looking for invoking the python function `f1` from tcl script

Comment: I get the error `can't find package tclpython`. I tried to install tclpython as `apt-get install tclpython` , but this says `can not find package tclpython`

Comment: are you using windows?

Comment: Tha't why, tclpython only works on windows, you can find the info here: http://wiki.tcl.tk/5630

Comment: so is there something on linux which can serve the purpose

Comment: I doubt about that, I would still suggest try to execute the python modules as stand alone, using the code I provided.